# Member of class not showing up in GameScene.swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make a game where you have a pig and where you swipe or hold the pig moves. I have a class for my pig with atributes but an error comes up in `GameScene.swift` saying `guy` is not a member of `porker`. Please help.

```
        import SpriteKit
        import UIKit

    class GameScene: SKScene {
    var porker:Porker!
    var touchLocation = CGFloat()
    var gameOver = false


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        addBG()
        addPig()
    }

    func addBG() {
        let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg");
        addChild(bg)
    }

    func addPig() {
        let Pig = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pig")
        porker = Porker(guy:Pig)
        addChild(Pig)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {


        for touch: AnyObject in touches{
            if !gameOver {
                touchLocation = (touch.locationInView(self.view!).y * -1) + (self.size.height/2)
            }

        }
        let MoveAction = SKAction.moveToY(touchLocation, duration: 0.5)
        MoveAction.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseOut
        Porker.guy.runAction(MoveAction)    }



    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

and here is the pig class

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Porker {

    var Guy:SKSpriteNode
    var speed = 0.1

    init(guy:SKSpriteNode){
        self.Guy = guy
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, variable/constants/parameter names should start with a lowercase, so you don't mix them up with class names. For example,

```
class Porker {
    var guy:SKSpriteNode
    var speed = 0.1

    init(guy:SKSpriteNode){
        self.guy = guy
    }
}
```

and inside touches began:

```
let moveAction = SKAction.moveToY(touchLocation, duration: 0.5)
moveAction.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseOut
porker.guy.runAction(MoveAction)
```

Hopefully that fixes things!

Comment: thanks so much i just wanted to let you know that you majorly helped me. I am acually pretty young (11 acually) and you have already made a change that helped me put my app on the app store soon. thx so much.